# XmlWriter to both String and File

Tags: c#, .net, xmlwriter

Can I use an XmlWriter to write to **both** a file and a string?

When writing to a file I do this:

```
using (var xw = XmlWriter.Create("myFile.xml"))
{
    //Build the xml
}
```

And when writing to a string I do this:

```
using (var sw = new StringWriter())
{
    using (var xw = XmlWriter.Create(sw))
    {
        // Build the xml
    }
    return sw.ToString();
}
```

But can I write to both a file and a string with the same XmlWriter instance?

Comment: Why don't write to string and then write this string to file, if needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a method like this:

```
private static void WriteXML(TextWriter writer)
{
    using (var xw = XmlWriter.Create(writer))
    {
        // Build the xml
    }
}
```

And then call it like:

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(...))
    WriteXML(sw);
```

to write a file or

```
string xml = String.Empty;
using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
{
    WriteXML(sw);
    xml = sw.ToString();
}
```

To create the string.

You could even create helper methods:

```
private static void WriteXMLFile(string fileName)
{
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(...))
        WriteXML(sw);
}

private static string GetXML()
{
    using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        WriteXML(sw);
        return sw.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a [composite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) `XmlWriter` which wraps many `XmlWriter` instances.

```
public class CompositeXmlWriter : XmlWriter
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<XmlWriter> writers;
    public CompositeXmlWriter(IEnumerable<XmlWriter> writers)
    {
        this.writers = writers;
    }

    public override void WriteStartDocument()
    {
        foreach (var writer in writers)
        {
            writer.WriteStartDocument();
        }
    }

    public override void WriteEndDocument()
    {
        foreach (var writer in writers)
        {
            writer.WriteEndDocument();
        }
    }

    ...Implement all other methods
}
```

Create your `CompositeXmlWriter` with other XmlWriters.

```
using (var xw = new CompositeXmlWriter(new[] { XmlWriter.Create("myFile.xml"), XmlWriter.Create(new StringWriter())})
{
    //Build the xml
}
```

Now whatever written in `xw` will be written in all the XmlWriters.